# friendly url don't recognize variable

Tags: php, .htaccess

I use in my `.htaccess`

`RewriteRule ^profiles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /profile.php?city=$1 [NC]`

Works normally when accessing the url:
`https://site.com.br/profiles/londres`

But in the page, after insert an variable `get`, the php recognizes only the variable configured in htaccess, example when accessing the url:

`https://site.com.br/profiles/londres?s=username`

`print_r($_GET);`
return
`Array ( [city] => londres)`

that is, it does not return the variable `s` in GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `QSA` flag in your rule to get query string as well.

```
RewriteRule ^profiles/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /profile.php?city=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Reference:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa